# How do I set Scala 2.10.3 Docs API to be used in Intellij IDEA 12?

Tags: api, scala, intellij-idea, documentation, editor

Setting Documentation URL in IDEA 12 to point to the unzipped "C:\scala-docs-2.10.3\" folder, doesn't work at all, i.e. the editor can't fetch the Scala documentation.

Next, I've tried with setting the web URL location of the [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#package), but it didn't worked also.

It is obvious that Scala API doesn't conform to the Java API directory structure, so IDEA cannot handle it appropriately.

Currently, IDEA settings for Scala are:

- Scala -> C:\scala-2.10.3\lib
- Scala Sources -> C:\scala-2.10.3\src
- Scala API -> C:\scala-docs-2.10.3

So, how do I set the Scala docs URL properly in IDEA 12?
Besides, I cannot fetch docs from Java sources too?

Answer (score 0):

Set your sources to `src/scala-library-src.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's no need to try it out right now as I have switched to IDEA 13 & Scala Plugin 0.26.327 and it works as expected. Thank you anyway.